# System clock runs behind

Tags: time, clock, system-date

The system clock of my PC (not a laptop) runs behind. What could be the cause?

Comment: As alex said in the top answer, "consider marking the answer as **accepted** if you thought it was helpful. It benefits all of us :)"

Comment: Not really an answer but make use of ntp servers, there's a setting in Windows called "Sync time with internet servers". Use that and you time will always be accurate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your CMOS battery that maintains the BIOS (and clock) information could have run out. Change it, it is usually a CR2032 battery and really easy to swap out on your motherboard.

[image]

Comment: This indeed did the trick. I looked at my motherboard's manual, where I found the type of the battery needed. And indeed, it was a common battery type (CR2032 like you said). Again, thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Another potential cause not listed here is the RTC crystal is failing or not behaving.

[image]

Comment: This comment requires *much* greater clarification.

Comment: 10 years later... I used to design motherboards and have seen (very few) instances where the RTC crystal didn't work. I didn't characterize the failure, I just replaced the part.

Comment: Okay, yes, just wait until the Internet has been around for 50 years! I read a bit about RTC crystals though it would be desirable to edit the post in a way that technical consumers could understand along with what action(s) they should take.

Answer (score 3):

CMOS battery, bug in the OS, I have seen it under systems with a heavy load losing time.  Possible when you run down the battery and it goes to sleep or hibernation you lose time.  If it's a new laptop I wouldn't worry about the CMOS battery, just use NTP.

Comment: Specifically use ntp.org (or one of the country/regional sub-domains). Most OSs will query on a regular interval to keep things correct.

Answer (score 2):

possibly a weak cmos backup battery?

Comment: Is that on the motherboard? Do you think this can be replaced?

Comment: yes and easily - someone seems to have answered with a picture of it as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Check your reginal settings (double click on the clock in the taskbar). You may need to check if the daylight savings box is correct and that your laptop believes it is in the correct timzone.