# CMOS Time problem

Tags: bios, date-time, cmos

Whenever i switch on the system an error is showing that Date & time is not correct. I have to set the time manually in bios to work the system. What is the reason for this error. How can i solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend replacing the CMOS battery if it's an old motherboard.

Comment: Your question might be related to this: http://superuser.com/questions/39496/system-clock-runs-behind

Comment: How can i get the model of CMOS battery for my motherboard.
my MB is intel845GLAD. Is it an easy process.I heard that battery may discharge, if didnt handled properly.

Comment: alex, you're a legend :)

Comment: @alex It is related..

Comment: cdb: Use a CR2032 (from page 29 of your motherboard's users manual). I've found that they are pretty easy to find. Look for a display at the store which has a bunch of different battery sizes.

Comment: @Randolph Potter: did I do something good or bad? :)

Comment: You linked to an existing article with pictures and everything. Legendary :).

Comment: Ah, so I did good. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Replace the battery. The battery type for Intel D845GLAD is CR2032 (see http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d845glad/sb/cs-008718.htm#20.0)

Comment: +1 for providing the additional information on the battery itself.